# Merge [meta:down-votes] and [meta:downvoting]

Tags: feature-request, meta, tag-merge

Here on meta, we have two tags regarding downvotes [down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes) and [downvoting](/questions/tagged/downvoting). Can we merge them into one?

Currently [down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes) has 8 questions and [downvoting](/questions/tagged/downvoting) has 63 questions.

In my opinion, though, we should use [down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes) as [upvoting](/questions/tagged/upvoting) does not exist while [up-votes](/questions/tagged/up-votes) does. This way we can keep it consistent.